# Как сделать такую маску css

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такое изображение. Как с помощью css сделать белый фон на нем. Скорее всего тут нужен псевдоэлемент с линейным градиентом, но не хватает понятия как сделать такой градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам тут больше box-shadow подойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так, правильней будет картинку фоном сделать, чтобы не мучится с `z-index`

```css
.shadow {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaCRY.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -240px 100px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `css mask`. Плюс: настоящая прозрачность. Минус: нет поддержки IE и Edge. Или вариант с псевдоэлементом и градиентом. Тут поддержка браузерами лучше, но цвет придётся подбирать под фон.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
.mask{
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to bottom,white 15%,transparent 50%);
}
.pseudo{
  position:relative;
}
.pseudo:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 15%,white 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  <img src="http://turdnevnikzima.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/irinazu2418-%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-0_8029b_eba72734_XL.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="pseudo">
  <img src="http://turdnevnikzima.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/irinazu2418-%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-0_8029b_eba72734_XL.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```